# In Odoo V11 CE, is it normal for the server to spend large amounts of time deleting bus.bus records?

Tags: logging, odoo, odoo-11, unlink

I've been having some problems with my Odoo installation and wish to get a better understanding of what normal behaviour for the Odoo server should be.

For instance, when looking at the odoo-server.log, for a few weeks now there are large numbers of entries where user #1 has deleted several hundred bus.bus records.

These entries occur at least every one or two minutes and sometimes two or three times within one minute.

Here is an example of the kind of log entry I'm seeing:

2021-01-14 00:00:13,104 3911 INFO XXXXXXXXX odoo.models.unlink: User #1 deleted bus.bus records with IDs: [27866710, 27866711, 27866712, 27866713, 27866714, 27866715, 27866716, 27866717, 27866718, 27866719, 27866720, 27866721, 27866722, 27866723, 27866724, 27866725, 27866726, 27866727, 27866728, 27866729, 27866730, 27866731, 27866732, 27866733, 27866734, 27866735, 27866736, 27866737, 27866738, 27866739, 27866740, 27866741, 27866742, 27866743, 27866744, 27866745, 27866746, 27866747, 27866748, 27866749, 27866750, 27866751, 27866752, 27866753, 27866754, 27866755, 27866756, 27866757, 27866758, 27866759, 27866760, 27866761, 27866762, 27866763, 27866764, 27866765, 27866766, 27866767, 27866768, 27866769, 27866770, 27866771, 27866772, 27866773, 27866774, 27866775, 27866776, 27866777, 27866778, 27866779, 27866780, 27866781, 27866782, 27866783, 27866784, 27866785, 27866786, 27866787, 27866788, 27866789, 27866790, 27866791, 27866792, 27866793, 27866794, 27866795, 27866796, 27866797, 27866798, 27866799, 27866800, 27866801, 27866802, 27866803, 27866804, 27866805, 27866806, 27866807, 27866808, 27866809, 27866810, 27866811, 27866812, 27866813, 27866814, 27866815, 27866816, 27866817, 27866818, 27866819, 27866820, 27866821, 27866822, 27866823, 27866824, 27866825, 27866826, 27866827, 27866828, 27866829, 27866830, 27866831, 27866832, 27866833, 27866834, 27866835, 27866836, 27866837, 27866838, 27866839, 27866840, 27866841, 27866842, 27866843, 27866844, 27866845, 27866846, 27866847, 27866848, 27866849, 27866850, 27866851, 27866852, 27866853, 27866854, 27866855, 27866856, 27866857, 27866858, 27866859, 27866860, 27866861, 27866862, 27866863, 27866864, 27866865, 27866866, 27866867, 27866868, 27866869, 27866870, 27866871, 27866872, 27866873, 27866874, 27866875, 27866876, 27866877, 27866878, 27866879, 27866880, 27866881, 27866882, 27866883, 27866884, 27866885, 27866886, 27866887, 27866888, 27866889, 27866890, 27866891, 27866892, 27866893, 27866894, 27866895, 27866896, 27866897, 27866898, 27866899, 27866900, 27866901, 27866902, 27866903, 27866904, 27866905, 27866906, 27866907, 27866908, 27866909, 27866910, 27866911, 27866912, 27866913, 27866914, 27866915, 27866916, 27866917, 27866918, 27866919, 27866920, 27866921, 27866922, 27866923, 27866924, 27866925, 27866926, 27866927, 27866928, 27866929, 27866930, 27866931, 27866932, 27866933, 27866934, 27866935, 27866936, 27866937, 27866938, 27866939, 27866940, 27866941, 27866942, 27866943, 27866944, 27866945, 27866946, 27866947, 27866948, 27866949, 27866950, 27866951, 27866952, 27866953, 27866954, 27866955, 27866956, 27866957, 27866958, 27866959, 27866960, 27866961, 27866962, 27866963, 27866964, 27866965, 27866966, 27866967, 27866968, 27866969, 27866970, 27866971, 27866972, 27866973, 27866974, 27866975, 27866976, 27866977, 27866978, 27866979, 27866980, 27866981, 27866982, 27866983, 27866984, 27866985, 27866986, 27866987, 27866988, 27866989, 27866990, 27866991, 27866992, 27866993, 27866994, 27866995, 27866996, 27866997, 27866998, 27866999, 27867000, 27867001, 27867002, 27867003, 27867004, 27867005, 27867006, 27867007, 27867008, 27867009, 27867010, 27867011, 27867012, 27867013, 27867014, 27867015, 27867016, 27867017, 27867018, 27867019, 27867020, 27867021, 27867022, 27867023, 27867024, 27867025, 27867026, 27867027, 27867028, 27867029, 27867030, 27867031, 27867032, 27867033, 27867034, 27867035, 27867036, 27867037, 27867038, 27867039, 27867040, 27867041, 27867042, 27867043, 27867044, 27867045, 27867046, 27867047, 27867048, 27867049, 27867050, 27867051, 27867052, 27867053, 27867054, 27867055, 27867056, 27867057, 27867058, 27867059, 27867060, 27867061, 27867062, 27867063, 27867064, 27867065, 27867066, 27867067, 27867068, 27867069, 27867070, 27867071, 27867072, 27867073, 27867074, 27867075, 27867076, 27867077, 27867078, 27867079, 27867080, 27867081, 27867082, 27867083, 27867084, 27867085, 27867086]

Is this typical behaviour or does it indicate something isn't working as it should?

I haven't encountered any missing records that I expect to be there, but I'm worried that records are being deleted when I don't want them to be.  Also, in order to do any kind of server operation like install or upgrade a module, I have to restart the server, otherwise I get the 'the server is busy right now...' error.  Then I have a small window to do that before the server get's locked up again with these unlink processes.

Answer (score 0):

It is an automatic task.

You should see how this task works in: Technical->Automation->Scheduled Actions , search the task by filters with "model" contains "bus". When you will find it, just modify the date of execution.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the question is more about whether the frequency of the actions, and also the volume of records being deleted (thousands every hour) that I describe, is normal.  Also, there is no scheduled action that matches "model" contains "bus" in my installation (V11 CE - latest code from Github as of yesterday).